# Loading images in recycler view with Glide

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am attempting to load images from firebase into a recycler adapter and display them

I have attempted two methods to try and solve this problem the first block of code resulted in the error"You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed)"

The second method the application ran but no images were loaded from reading other similar issues I have seen the isAdded() check but I couldn't seem to get that to work the images are being uploaded into a folder in firebase called post_images and the rest of the data associated with the post (Instagram like app with posting) are in firestore

```
public BlogRecyclerAdapter(List<BlogPost> blog_list) {

    this.blog_list = blog_list;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String desc_data = blog_list.get(position).getDesc();
    holder.setDescText(desc_data);

    String image_url = blog_list.get(position).getImage_url();
    holder.setBlogImage(image_url);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return blog_list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View mView;

    private TextView descView;
    private ImageView blogImageView;
    public Context mContext;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDescText(String descText) {

        descView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_desc);
        descView.setText(descText);

    }

    public void setBlogImage(final String downloadUri) {

        blogImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.Post_image_view);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(downloadUri).into(blogImageView);


    }}}
```

Other method attempted

```
        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        final String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);
        mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_uid + (".jpeg"));
                Log.d("heere", "S");

                // This gets the download url async
                filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        //The download url
                        final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                        Log.d("tag", downloadUrl);
                        if (!downloadUrl.equals("default")) {

                            Glide.with(mContext).load(downloadUrl).into(blogImageView);

                        //    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(downloadUrl).into(mDisplayImage);


                        }
                    }});}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });}}}
```

I would like the image to be displayed in the recycler view

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change this line

> ```
> Glide.with(mContext).load(downloadUri).into(blogImageView);
> ```

to this instead:

```
Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(downloadUri).into(blogImageView);
```

All `ViewHolder` instances have a field `itemView` that is guaranteed to be non-null, and you can get the context from that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your mContext is not initialized
2. mContext must be a RecyclerView.Adapter global variable and not a ViewHolder variable
3. mContext must initialize in onCreateViewHolder function this way

   ```
    this.mContext = parent.getContext();
   ```